# PropertyInfo for property at the end of a chain of properties

Tags: c#, reflection

I have something like this:

```
class OriginalClass
{
    public Type2 object2 { get; set; }
}

class Type2
{
    public Type3 object3 { get; set; }
}

class Type3
{
    public Type4 object4 { get; set; }
}

var obj = new OriginalClass();
var object4 = obj.object2.object3.object4;
```

I also have a string value:
`"object2.object3.object4"`

This is the path from a type `T` to `object4` via `object2` and `object3` (both properties which returns objects). `object4` is the property on `object3`.

How can I create a `PropertyInfo` object for the last property `"object4"` dynamically?

Comment: Your question is rather vague. It's the type of `object2` which is of interest. What problem are you actually trying to solve here? This looks like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/284827).

Comment: @WaiHaLee Lets consider this as OBJ.object2.object3.object4 where OBJ is an instance of Type T. I want to get the propertyInfo object for the last property object4 using reflection

Comment: I've edited your question to include some code which I think covers what you are trying to ask. Feel free to revert it if this isn't what you had in mind, but I think people will struggle to help you with your question as it was.

Comment: I've also edited your title. 'nested object' implies a nested class (i.e. a class whose definition is *inside* another).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code below you could do something like:

```
PropertyInfo pi = GetPropertyInfoFromPath(obj.GetType(), "object2.object3.object4");
```

I still need to get around to publishing this as a nugget but here is an excerpt from my reflection library.

```
public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfoFromPath<T>(string path)
{
  var type = typeof(T);
  return GetPropertyInfoFromPath(type, path);
}

public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfoFromPath(Type type, string path)
{
  var parts = path.Split('.');
  var count = parts.Count();

  if (count == 0)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Not a valid path");

  if (count == 1)
    return GetPropertyInformation(type, parts.First());
  else
  {
     var t = GetPropertyInformation(type, parts[0]).PropertyType;
     return GetPropertyInfoFromPath(t, string.Join(".", parts.Skip(1)));
  }
}
```

If you did want to use expression (better if possible as it is refactor safe)

```
public static Type GetPropertyType<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var info = GetPropertyInformation(expression) as PropertyInfo;
        return info.PropertyType;
    }

    public static MemberInfo GetPropertyInformation<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> propertyExpression)
    {
        return PropertyInformation(propertyExpression.Body);
    }

    public static PropertyInfo PropertyInformation(Expression propertyExpression)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpr = propertyExpression as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpr == null)
        {
            UnaryExpression unaryExpr = propertyExpression as UnaryExpression;
            if (unaryExpr != null && unaryExpr.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
            {
                memberExpr = unaryExpr.Operand as MemberExpression;
            }
        }

        if (memberExpr != null)
        {
            var propertyMember = memberExpr.Member as PropertyInfo;
            if (propertyMember != null)
                return propertyMember;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Test.

```
[Fact]
public void GetPropertyInfo_FromInstanceNestedPropertyUsingPathString_ReturnsPropertyInfo()
{
        var deepType = Helper.GetPropertyInfoFromPath<TestModel>("Nested.Deep");
        var deepDeclaringType = Helper.GetPropertyInfoFromPath<TestModel>("Nested");

        Assert.Equal(typeof(string), deepType.PropertyType);
        Assert.Equal(typeof(NestedModel), deepDeclaringType.PropertyType);
}
```

Classes.

```
public class TestModel : Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [PickMe]
    public string MyString { get; set; }

    public NestedModel Nested { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClosedAt { get; set; }
}

public class NestedModel
{
    public string Deep { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may implement an extension method like the following one:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    /// <summary>Looks for a property using an object path where each
    /// property to match is accessed using dot syntax</summary>
    public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyByPath(this Type someType, string objectPath, BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    {
        string[] objectPathParts = objectPath.Split('.');

        // #1 property in the object path should be obtained from T
        PropertyInfo currentProperty = someType.GetProperty(objectPathParts[0], bindingFlags);
        for (int propertyIndex = 1; propertyIndex < objectPathParts.Length; propertyIndex++)
        {
            // While all other association properties should be obtained
            // accessing PropertyInfo.PropertyType
            currentProperty = currentProperty.PropertyType.GetProperty(objectPathParts[propertyIndex], bindingFlags);
            if (currentProperty == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Some property in the object path doesn't exist", "objectPath");
        }

        return currentProperty;
    }
}
```

And later use it as follows:

```
PropertyInfo object4Info = typeof(OriginalClass).GetPropertyByPath("object2.object3.object4");
```

### Approach #2: Using expression trees. Even better and simpler!

You can also solve the issue using less reflection:

```
public static class ReflectionHelper
{
    public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyByPath<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> pathExpr)
    {
        // It must be a member access expression like "x.y.z"
        MemberExpression propertyAccessExpr = pathExpr.Body as MemberExpression;

        // if it's not a member access expression, return null
        if(propertyAccessExpr == null)
            return null;

        return propertyAccessExpr.Member as PropertyInfo;
    }
}
```

And later get last property info in the path as follows:

```
PropertyInfo object4Info = ReflectionHelper
     .GetPropertyByPath<OriginalClass>(c => c.object2.object3.object4);
```